# Archived IPA size for Appstore is larger then Adhoc

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift2, app-store

I am developing app in  swift 2 in xcode 7.3. I used too small images and project is too short it contains only one framework googleMobileAds.framework. My total size of project folder is only 36MB where 31MB is only for googleMobileAds.framework. 
Now I want to publish my app on store. but it creates too large ipa with size 31 MB for app store deployment. When i tried to export ipa for adhoc exported IPA file size with 8MB. I searched a lot on google and i got to know that disabling of BITCODE will help I disabled but nothing worked its still 31 MB for App Store Deployement. please tell me how to reduce app size because app is too small thats why I want to reduce app size.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Don't worry about it.  There is a lot more information submitted to the app store than is included in the final download.  Once Apple packages it, it will be the same size as the ad-hoc package

Comment: means when app will launch to app store app size will automatically reduce ?

Comment: Yes, your app store submission includes information that Apple needs to analyse your app

Comment: ok it means after publishing app size will be around 8 mb. thanks :)

Comment: @sohanvanani can you please share that its true that after upload app its size is same as adhoc ipa .
Because i am getting same issue and i am scared that after upload it will not impact on size of ipa

Answer (score 9, accepted):

App store distribution submissions are uncompressed (and App Store downloads are less compressible than development ipa files), so this is normal and there is nothing you can do (except remove lots of code or data from your app).